# React issue with route

Tags: reactjs

I have started to experiment with react following this tutorial: http://courses.reactjsprogram.com/

I have the following code for my route.s

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
var hashHistory = ReactRouter.hashHistory;
var Main = require('../components/Main');
var Home = require('../components/Home');
var PromptContainer = require('../containers/PromptContainer');

var routes = (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Main}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path='playerOne'            header='Player One' component={PromptContainer} />
            <Route path='playerTwo/:playerOne' header='Player Two' component={PromptContainer} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

and PromptContainer.js as follow:

```
var React = require('react');

var PromptContainer = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="jumbotron col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
                <h1>{this.props.route.header}</h1>
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Github Username"
                                type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                            <button
                                className="btn btn-block btn-success"
                                type="submit">
                                    Continue
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } 
});

module.exports = PromptContainer;
```

index.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var routes = require('./config/routes');

ReactDOM.render(
    routes,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

when viewed in the browser I get the following error:

index_bundle.js:21001 Warning: [react-router] Location "//playerTwo" did not match any routes

Any help?

Comment: What's the URL you are trying to access when you get this error?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/#/playerTwo?_k=o2efmq

Comment: did you try playerTwo/<something> ? , you didn't define /playerTwo router

Comment: What do you mean by "define"?

Answer (score 1):

You are importing "Route" incorrectly.

this

```
var Route = ReactRouter.Router;
```

should be

```
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
```

Comment: I have already changed that, but I still get the error. Thanks for the head up though

Answer (score 0):

You have a route defined for `/playerTwo/USERNAME` but no route defined for just `/playerTwo/`, thus the error.  The code only knows how to handle that URL when it also has the PlayerOne username on the end.

Unfortunately your code doesn't pass the PlayerOne username into the route - to do that, you'll need a few extra functions to handle grabbing the input value and appending it to the URL.

Checkout [Video 5 in the React.js Fundamentals course](http://courses.reactjsprogram.com/courses/reactjsfundamentals/lectures/760395) for the step-by-step answer on how to handle it all.